# Displaying a bootstrap modal on page load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a `modal` that i need to popup when the page loads. However existing code i have doesn't display it(nothing appears to happen). The existing code was used to display it from a `table` row click. (this worked perfectly.)

I have then experimented with this new code snippet which displays the `modal` on page load though it displays it incorrectly.

I have 3 questions. (If they need to be put into different posts please let me know)

1. whats the difference between my `table` row click code and the new snippet I'm trying (NOT the event part but the actual displaying of the modal part).
2. Why is the new snippet not displaying correctly.
3. best way to get my desired result. (Display the `modal` correctly on page load)

---

on table row click (this code worked correctly):

```
 $(document).ready(function ($) {
     $(".table_row_click1").click(function (e) {
         $(this).attr('data-target', "#myModal");
         $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
     });
 });
```

new snippet i was trying:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

`modal`:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel'
  aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable' role='document'>
     <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
           <h3 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>Supplier information</h3>
           <button class='close' type='button' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
           <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='ids'>ID:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_id" class="form-control" required='required'  type="text" placeholder="" readonly></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='name'>Name:<span style="color:red">*</span></label><input runat="server" id="modal_name"  class='form-control firstname' required='required' type='text' name='name'
              placeholder='Enter first name' /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='country'>Country:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_country"  class='form-control lastname'  type='text' name='country' placeholder='Enter Country' 
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='state'>State:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_state"  class='form-control phone'  type='text' name='state' placeholder='Enter State'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='street_name'>Street Name:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_street_name"  class='form-control email'  type='text' name='street_name' placeholder='Enter Street Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='street_number'>Street #:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_street_number"  class='form-control address' type='text' name='street_number' placeholder='Enter Street #'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='phone1'>Phone # 1:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_phone_number_1"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='phone1'  placeholder='Enter Phone # 1'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='phone2'>Phone # 2:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_phone_number_2"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='phone2'  placeholder='Enter Phone # 2'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='email1'>Email 1:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_email_1"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='email1'  placeholder='Enter Email 1'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='email2'>Email 2:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_email_2"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='email2'  placeholder='Enter Email 2'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_first_name'>Rep First Name:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_first_name"  class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='rep_first_name'   placeholder='Enter Rep First Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_last_name'>Rep Last Name:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_last_name"  class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='rep_last_name'  placeholder='Enter Rep Last Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_phone'>Rep Phone #:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_phone_number"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='rep_phone'  placeholder='Enter Rep Phone #'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_email'>Rep Email:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_email"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='rep_email'  placeholder='Enter Rep Email'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='website'>Website:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_website"  class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='website'  placeholder='Enter Website'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='gender' >Active:<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
              <span  style="color:green"><input runat="server" id="modal_active_true"    required='required'  type='radio' name='Active' value='True' />True</span>
              <span  style="color:red"><input runat="server" id="modal_active_false"   required='required' type='radio' name='Active' value='False' />False</span>
           </div>
           <button class='btn btn-primary btn-save-change'
              type='submit'>Save changes</button>
        </div>

     </div>
  </div>
```

incorrect displaying with new on page load snippet:

[image]

Its position is not correct, the background does not fade, and when i click on it it disappears. (The on table row click method does not have these issues associated with the modal)

correct displaying with table row click snippet:
[image]

Comment: try `.modal('show')` insted of `.modal('toggle')`

Comment: @Joseph Thank you however the result was the same.

Comment: is there any error in your `console`?

Comment: Hmm, i never thought to look there. There are two errors that i will google now.

error 1: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
error 2: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Do you know what these would be?

Comment: the 500 server error might be the reason for that

Comment: Would you know how to get more info on those errors?

Comment: To know specifically what part is causing that error?

Comment: it looks that you get your data from `ajax` request and that request comes with error,
so try to debug your code in server side first and then back to the front

Comment: I am not trying to call any data currently, it should display with blank data. I am testing just the displaying of the modal at this point

Comment: try to check where this errors come from by click on the line for this error from your console

Answer (score 1):

1) The scripts does not produce the same results because they are not equivalent: they target different events (`ready` in the jquery script, and `load` in the js script).

The "correct" (but not advisable) equivalent script would be to add this to your body:

```
<script>
   $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
</script>
```

2) The second script does not produce the desired results because on windows load the modal is yet not existing, hence it cannot open.

3) The "best" way, intended as cleaner and coherent (pure JQuery) solution is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

/------------------------ EDIT ------------------------------------/

Tried the solution in "stand-alone" and it works, maybe the issue comes from the integration in your code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel'
  aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable' role='document'>
     <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
           <h3 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>Supplier information</h3>
           <button class='close' type='button' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
           <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='ids'>ID:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_id" class="form-control" required='required'  type="text" placeholder="" readonly></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='name'>Name:<span style="color:red">*</span></label><input runat="server" id="modal_name"  class='form-control firstname' required='required' type='text' name='name'
              placeholder='Enter first name' /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='country'>Country:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_country"  class='form-control lastname'  type='text' name='country' placeholder='Enter Country' 
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='state'>State:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_state"  class='form-control phone'  type='text' name='state' placeholder='Enter State'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='street_name'>Street Name:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_street_name"  class='form-control email'  type='text' name='street_name' placeholder='Enter Street Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='street_number'>Street #:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_street_number"  class='form-control address' type='text' name='street_number' placeholder='Enter Street #'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='phone1'>Phone # 1:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_phone_number_1"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='phone1'  placeholder='Enter Phone # 1'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='phone2'>Phone # 2:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_phone_number_2"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='phone2'  placeholder='Enter Phone # 2'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='email1'>Email 1:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_email_1"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='email1'  placeholder='Enter Email 1'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='email2'>Email 2:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_email_2"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='email2'  placeholder='Enter Email 2'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_first_name'>Rep First Name:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_first_name"  class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='rep_first_name'   placeholder='Enter Rep First Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_last_name'>Rep Last Name:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_last_name"  class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='rep_last_name'  placeholder='Enter Rep Last Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_phone'>Rep Phone #:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_phone_number"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='rep_phone'  placeholder='Enter Rep Phone #'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_email'>Rep Email:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_rep_email"  class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='rep_email'  placeholder='Enter Rep Email'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='website'>Website:</label><input runat="server" id="modal_website"  class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='website'  placeholder='Enter Website'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='gender' >Active:<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
              <span  style="color:green"><input runat="server" id="modal_active_true"    required='required'  type='radio' name='Active' value='True' />True</span>
              <span  style="color:red"><input runat="server" id="modal_active_false"   required='required' type='radio' name='Active' value='False' />False</span>
           </div>
           <button class='btn btn-primary btn-save-change'
              type='submit'>Save changes</button>
        </div>

     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I apologise i worded question number 1 poorly. I know the difference in the events that trigger the functions. Though I don't know the difference between $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); and $(this).attr('data-target', "#myModal");
                    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

Comment: I tried your best way of doing it and it still displays incorrectly. i.e its position is not correct, the background does not fade, and when i click on it it disappears.